# Ошибка bound method Employee.calculate_late_arrival of <Employee: mark>

Tags: python, datetime, время

Делаю приложение для отслеживания опозданий. У меня есть модели `employyee` и `attendance`, и я в модели `employyee` прописал функцию, которая высчитывает начало работы время и прихода на работу. К сожалению, функция выдает ошибки. Вот код:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    phone_id = models.IntegerField()
    salary = models.IntegerField()
    daily_salary = models.IntegerField()
    office = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='офис')
    post = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    penalty = models.IntegerField()
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def calculate_late_arrival(self):
        try:
            start_time_default = Attendance.start_time_default  # Предполагается, что это поле datetime
            start_time_employee = self.start_time  # Предполагается, что это поле datetime


            time_difference = start_time_employee - start_time_default


            return str(time_difference)
        except Attendance.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return "N/A"  # Если информация о посещении отсутствует

    calculate_late_arrival.short_description = 'Опоздание'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


    {class Attendance(models.Model):
        employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee,on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='посещение', null=True, blank=True)
        office = models.ForeignKey(Office, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        start_time_default = models.DateTimeField()
        end_time_default = models.DateTimeField()
    }

админка:

        @admin.register(Employee)
    class EmployeeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        inlines = [AdvanceInline]
        actions = [view_attendance, start_timer, stop_timer, ]
        list_display = ['first_name', 'start_time', 'salary', 'daily_salary', 'office', 'post', 'get_late_arrival', 'remaining_salary', ]
    
        def get_late_arrival(self, obj):
            return obj.calculate_late_arrival()
    
        get_late_arrival.short_description = 'Опоздание'
        def remaining_salary(self, obj):
            total_penalty = obj.penalty
            salary = obj.daily_salary
            remaining_salary = salary - total_penalty
            return remaining_salary
    
        remaining_salary.short_description = 'Оставшаяся зарплата'
```